# App crash after image capture from webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

try to capture image from `webview`.Its working fine but in galaxy note 3 operating on android lollipop 5.0 it crashes after clicking select button.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // For Android 5.0
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                //qrCodeReaderView.stopCamera();
                mFilePathCallback = filePath;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI
                    );
                } else {

                }
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                return true;

            }

        });
```

Logcat:

```
11-28 01:00:54.473 D/Activity(13624): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-28 01:00:54.473 D/Activity(13624): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-28 01:00:54.473 E/Main    (13624): cancel timer
11-28 01:00:54.893 E/Main    (13624): Invoking logout timer
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624): 
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.shashank.gaintz.WebViewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1de4327 V.E..... R......D 0,0-144,144} that was originally added here
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:465)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:277)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:312)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at com.shashank.gaintz.WebViewActivity$2.onPageStarted(WebViewActivity.java:327)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:190)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:20)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
11-28 01:00:54.963 E/WindowManager(13624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
11-28 01:00:55.023 D/Activity(13624): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-28 01:00:55.023 D/Activity(13624): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-28 01:00:55.023 E/Main    (13624): cancel timer
11-28 01:00:55.133 E/ViewRootImpl(13624): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
11-28 01:00:55.133 I/Timeline(13624): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@260d2f13 time:22633932
11-28 01:00:55.133 I/Timeline(13624): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@260d2f13 time:22633932
11-28 01:00:55.553 D/AndroidRuntime(13624): Shutting down VM
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1de4327 V.E..... R......D 0,0-144,144} not attached to window manager
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:402)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:328)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:431)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:414)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at com.shashank.gaintz.WebViewActivity$2.onPageFinished(WebViewActivity.java:307)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:199)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:72)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
11-28 01:00:55.553 E/ReportHandler(13624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
11-28 01:00:55.563 I/Timeline(13624): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.shashank.gaintz time:22634360
11-28 01:00:55.633 I/Process (13624): Sending signal. PID: 13624 SIG: 9
11-28 01:00:55.803 E/SELinux (14806): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-28 01:00:55.803 I/art     (14806): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-28 01:00:55.823 D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(14806): TimaSignature is unavailable
11-28 01:00:55.823 D/ActivityThread(14806): Added TimaKeyStore provider
11-28 01:00:55.863 E/SELinux (14823): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-28 01:00:55.863 I/art     (14823): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-28 01:00:55.873 D/ResourcesManager(14806): creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.shashank.gaintz-1/base.apk
11-28 01:00:55.893 D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(14823): TimaSignature is unavailable
11-28 01:00:55.893 D/ActivityThread(14823): Added TimaKeyStore provider
```

Comment: post the log please

Comment: What are you doing in the function `onActivityResult()`

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{mCapturedImageURI});
        mFilePathCallback = null;}

Comment: logcat is
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.gaintz/com.shashank.gaintz.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.gaintz/com.shashank.gaintz.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.webkit.ValueCallback.onReceiveValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3390)
 at